# Remove white edges from image C#

Tags: c#, image, edge-detection

I am looking for a way to detect and crop a image in scan I am receiving. The picture is a form that gets scanned as a result it also contains the white background of scan cover.

Any suggestions how I could do that automatically?

Comment: Perhaps this will be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898050/how-to-determine-edges-in-an-image-optimally

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 0):

There is an algorithm (with examples) for use in just this scanning situation:

https://github.com/rajbot/autocrop

It is not c# but it should be simple to migrate much of it without significant difficulty.

There is also a simpler algorithm which may fit your needs written in VB for .net here:

http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=1755&lngWId=10